# Python GTK3 Combobox make text entry bold or with colored background

Tags: python, combobox, gtk3

I have a GTK widget for selecting my printers and show them in a ComboBox widget.

How can I make the default printer entry **bold** or with **red background**?

I am not sure how to do this or whether it is possible at all.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import Gdk

import os 
import sys 
import subprocess

class SystemPrinter(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Window Name")
        box = Gtk.HBox()
        self.add(box)
        printers, default_printer = self.get_system_printers()
        default_printer_entry = 0
        printers_store = Gtk.ListStore(str, int)
        for n, item in enumerate(printers.items()):
            printers_store.append(item)
            if item[0] == default_printer:
                default_printer_entry = n
        printers_combo = Gtk.ComboBox.new_with_model_and_entry(printers_store)
        printers_combo.set_entry_text_column(0)
        printers_combo.set_active(default_printer_entry)
        box.pack_start(Gtk.Label("Printer", True, True, 0), False, False, 0)
        box.pack_start(printers_combo, False, False, 0)
        self.show_all()

    def get_system_printers(self):
        printers = {}
        default_printer = ""
        printers_raw = subprocess.check_output("lpstat -p -d", shell=True)
        n = 0
        for printer in printers_raw.split("\n"):
            if "printer" in printer.split(" ")[0]:
                printers[printer.split(" ")[1]] = n
                n += 1
            elif  "system" in printer.split(" ")[0]:
                default_printer = printer.split(" ")[3]
        return printers, default_printer

    def main(self):
        Gtk.main()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = SystemPrinter()
    s.main()
```

edit: I want to highlight the an default entry of a combobox before I select it!

Answer (score 2):

First off, changing background colors (or fonts for that matter) is not encouraged in modern Gtk versions, and most methods are either deprecated or don't work consistently. The idea is that anything 'appearance'-related should be in CSS definitions.

You can still change the font of widgets by calling the `modify_font` method of the `ComboBox`'s entry widget. These are the steps involved:

- Realize that a `ComboBox` is a container widget which contains the GtkEntry you see on the screen. So 'find' the entry by calling `get_child()` (which is an inherited method) on the `ComboBox`.
- Then call `modify_font` on the entry widget. You need to provide the new font as created by eg. Pango's `font_description()`.

You might be tempted to use the `override_background()` method to change the color, but that doesn't seem to work reliably (and is deprecated).

Comment: Hello. That is not exactly what I want. Because you cannot see which entry / text is the default before you have selected it. You only see after selection. But thank you. With your info I can make the selected entry bold and give them a background color:

        if child.get_text() == self.default_printer:
            child.modify_font(Pango.FontDescription("bold"))
            entry_style_context.add_class("green")
        else:
            child.modify_font(None)
            entry_style_context.remove_class("green")

Comment: I'd have answered earlier, but just back from an operation. You can preselect items from the store connected to the combobox by selecting it (If I recall correctly, by setting 'active_item')

Comment: I upvoted this because it helped solve my problem; modify_font still works. I think it is not a good idea to tell people that they should avoid something - often they have a valid use case nonetheless, and that is then not answered, so my upvote is mostly due to the specific hints given, via code, HOW to solve it. I am even still using ruby-gtk2 in 2020, oddly enough - don't quite feel the vibe around gtk3, and gtk4 is soon released ...

Comment: "I think it is not a good idea to tell people that they should avoid something". I agree completely, and don't recommend anything. On the other hand, if the authors deprecate something, I do think it's wise to not use it, or be prepared to maintain the program later (which I like less). (IMO) Gtk3 started off shakily with many initial decisions (particularly CSS)  changing and annoying people. It's quite usable now. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make text appear bold, you could try, for example, `Gtk.Label.set_markup(<b>"this text will be bold</b>)`.